# Display messages formatted using JSON in webpage

Tags: json, html

I've an application that creates messages formatted using JSON.
What's the simplest/best way to show these messages in a web-page that updates every 5 minutes.
I've no experiences using JSON so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of web technology are you going to be using?

Comment: Not decided yet. Depends on the advice. As simple and light weighted as possible because it's only status info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[If you use jquery then refer to jquery's api doc for examples](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

[If you use yui then refer to yui's apidoc for examples](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/json/)

you also need to set a timeout for repeating the action in every 5 mins. You probably will find good examples for this in every major JavaScript framework manual that you might be using

Answer (score 2):

There are various options, depending on how you have implemented your application a reasonably clean and light weight possiblity is having your application make the messages available through a REST http interface at a specific URL.

Using a javascript standard library/framework jquery 'GET' request the messages every 5 minutes from the url.

The library will recieve the JSON object and be able to process is accordingly displaying the message in your browser.

There are vairous other options such as [web sockets](http://www.websockets.org/aboutwebsocket.html), however these are very much for more real time communication using push, it sounds like  your case can be handled with a pull.